# use vertical percentage for css - height: x%;

Tags: css, layout, fluid-layout

I am trying to make a fluid layout for an app and am having some trouble with using css for height percentages. It is using the horizontal size of the window to specify the height % when I want it to be getting this percentage from the vertical size of the window. Is this possible or am I out of luck?

```
width: x%;
height: y%;
```

x and y being the percentage that I want the element to be. Both are being determined by the horizontal size of the window, and I want each to use it's respective axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use JavaScript to update the absolute height of the parent node, height % begins to mean something. From playing around, a P or DIV as first generation child of the body ignores any CSS height%; Wrap it in something with an absolute height. If you don't know the height before hand, use an onload JS function to set it.

Comment: I was hoping I wasn't going to have to use js, but that does seem like the only option at this point. Thanks for the help!