# 3 x 3 grid relative to viewport size in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a 3 x 3 grid with with each  taking height and width values of 30% (I would like to avoid vh, vw and vm units):

```
section {
display:inline-block;
padding: 0.5% 0.5%;
margin: 0.5% 0.5%;
box-sizing:border-box;
width: 30%;
height: 30%;
border: #000 solid 1px; 
}
```

However, whilst the width is always 30% the height does fix at this value, so when the first section has more text in than the second, it ends up much taller.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/GzCPw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure browsers don't accept height in precentage values. Use javascript to dynamically update an absolute height value.

See here: [use vertical percentage for css - height: x%;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129521/use-vertical-percentage-for-css-height-x)