# CSS fluid grid - div height doesn't adjust

Tags: css, layout, fluid

I'm using the fluid grid system below.

```
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF TWELVE  */
.span_12_of_12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span_11_of_12 {
    width: 91.53%;
}
.span_10_of_12 {
    width: 83.06%;
}

.span_9_of_12 {
    width: 74.6%;
}

.span_8_of_12 {
    width: 66.13%;
}

.span_7_of_12 {
    width: 57.66%;
}

.span_6_of_12 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

.span_5_of_12 {
    width: 40.73%;
}

.span_4_of_12 {
    width: 32.26%;
}

.span_3_of_12 {
    width: 23.8%;
}

.span_2_of_12 {
    width: 15.33%;
}

.span_1_of_12 {
    width: 6.866%;
}
```

I want to create a button and I want the height to contract/expand as the width does. I also would like the height to be a portion of the parent div and be vertically aligned. Here is the html:

```
<header class="section group header">
        <img class="col span_8_of_12" src="img/logo.png">
        <div class="col span_1_of_12">

        </div>
        <div class="col span_3_of_12 call-to-action">
            <a href="offer.html">Get An Offer</a> 
        </div>
</header>
```

`.call-to-action { height: 30%; margin-top: 20%; }` doesn't do anything. Height only works with pixels. Margin-top doesn't work as pixels or percentage.

I feel like there should be a CSS solution to this. I would like all elements to adjust proportionately - height and width. Fluid grid seems to only adjust the width.

Thanks for any input

---

The height of the get an offer button doesn't expand. Also, I'd like the get an offer button to be at level with the words in the logo. The logo size increases with the fluid width, meaning the margin-top of the button would have to adjust too.
[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tK6A.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiLi9.png)

Comment: may you attach an image of what you want?by the way , i think you can fine answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129576/3828573)

Comment: I added images above

Comment: I see the link. Is Javascript the only way?

Comment: why shouldn't you height scale with px and change px on different screens?even why you don't user css frameworks like bootstrap?

Comment: if you want to scale height by % (percent), i should say it's impossible for "position: relative;" it's only work for "fixed" or "absolute" position, you can test "height:100vh" but i myself do not do this.then the only way is javascript on your case

Comment: Gotcha thanks. I think I'm gonna skip fluid on this one. I'll start using it once I'm incorporating javascript.

Comment: There is no need for JavaScript. First get all the columns to equal height by either making them `table-cell`s (and parent as table, no floats) or by using flexbox. Please note that anchor tags `<a>` by default are inline, so you'd have to set `display:inline-block` and `height:100%`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I appreciate it